# What am I misunderstanding in a paper using the Abel's functional equation?

Tags: functional-equations, neural-networks

I'm currently reading the paper available at https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05724.

In this paper, the authors define a function iteration as shown here:
[image: function iteration].

They also discuss Abel's functional equation:
[image: Abel function].

Given that $f(x) = e^x$ and $\beta = 1$, the equation $$\psi(f(x)) = \psi(x) + \beta$$ simplifies to $$\psi(e^x) = \psi(x) + 1.$$ If we substitute $\log^{(k)}(x) + k$ for $\psi(x)$, we obtain the equation $$\log^{(k)}(e^x) + k = \log^{(k)}(x) + k + 1.$$

However, this doesn't seem to hold true for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where $0 \le \log^{(k)}(x) < 1$.
For instance, if $k = 1$, which belongs to $\mathbb{N}$, we get $x = \log(x) + 1$, but this only holds true when $x = 1$.

Could someone clarify what I might be missing or misunderstanding in this scenario?

Comment: Lol the neural networks tag!

Comment: @A rural reader. Indeed a neural networks paper going back centuries to the roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [known and easy to see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation) that Abel's functional equation
$$\tag1
\psi(f(x))=\psi(x)+1
$$
is equivalent to
$$\tag2
f(h(x))=h(x+1)
$$ when $\psi$ is invertible. In fact,
$h=\psi^{-1}\,.$ The question how to solve
$\exp(h(x))=h(x+1)$ is handled for example in
[this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-267/S0025-5718-09-02188-7/S0025-5718-09-02188-7.pdf).

Now to your [arxiv.org/abs/1503.05724](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05724):

They take $f(x)=e^x\,.$ When we interpret $\log^{(k)}(x)$ naively as
$$
\log\circ\log\dots\circ\log\,,\text{ ($k$ times) }
$$
then their function
$$\tag3
\psi(x)=\log^{(k)}(x)+k
$$
does ***not*** solve (1). Not even for $k=1\,:$
$$
\log(e^x)+1=x+1\not=\log x+2\,.
$$
It seems to me that (3) is a failed attempt to find a ***just a notation*** that is supposed to reflect the fact
that every invertible solution $\psi$ of (1) with $f(x)=e^x$ must satisfy
$$\tag4
\exp^{(k)}(x)=\psi^{-1}(\psi(x)+k)\,
$$
where $\exp^{(k)}$ is the usual $k$-fold iterate of $\exp\,.$